# Is there a way to JOIN two tables where either table could return no results?

Tags: oracle

Let's say there is table A and table B.
Table A --

| Person ID | BloodPressure | HeartRate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 140/77 | 88 |
| 2 | 138/75 | 76 |

Table B --

| Person ID | HeightInches | WeightLbs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 68 | 170 |
| 3 | 71 | 165 |

I'm looking for a way to select from both tables in a single query, but am having issues figuring out a JOIN that produces my desired results and am starting to think that a JOIN might not be the proper way to do this.

If I do

```
SELECT A.BloodPressure, A.HeartRate, B.HeightInches, B.WeightLbs 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.PersonId = B.PersonId 
WHERE A.PersonId = 1
```

then, I get desired results in the form of

| Person ID | BloodPressure | HeartRate | HeightInches | WeightLbs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 140/77 | 88 | 68 | 170 |

When using the same query to look for the data of PersonId = 3, it simply returns no results.

If using PersonId = 2, the results are still acceptable by virtue of a result row existing.

| Person ID | BloodPressure | HeartRate | HeightInches | WeightLbs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 138/75 | 76 | NULL | NULL |

I think understand why PersonId = 3 would not return any results; the SELECT on table A doesn't return anything so when it comes time to JOIN, there is no PatientId value present to identify which row in table B should be joined with.

I'd like to be able to get a result table with all of the columns from table A and table B, it's okay if the actual values from either table are null, I just need to find a way to get a result from the case where PersonId = 3 without knowing in advance which tables contain data for the corresponding PersonId.

Is what I'm looking for achievable? If so, what changes need to be made to the SELECT query?

Comment: A `FULL OUTER JOIN` would be athe way to solve this. You'll want to combine with `COALESCE()` to ensure the ID from either table is returned: `SELECT COALESCE(A.PersonID, B.PersonID) as PersonID, a.BloodPressure ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about full outer join with `in` in `where` clause?

```
SQL> with
  2  ta (id, pressure, heart) as
  3    (select 1, '140/77', 88 from dual union all
  4     select 2, '138/75', 76 from dual
  5    ),
  6  tb (id, height, weight) as
  7    (select 1, 68, 170 from dual union all
  8     select 3, 71, 165 from dual
  9    )
 10  select ta.*, tb.*
 11  from ta full outer join tb on ta.id = tb.id
 12  where &par_value in (ta.id, tb.id);
Enter value for par_value: 1

        ID PRESSU      HEART         ID     HEIGHT     WEIGHT
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 140/77         88          1         68        170

SQL> /
Enter value for par_value: 2

        ID PRESSU      HEART         ID     HEIGHT     WEIGHT
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 138/75         76

SQL> /
Enter value for par_value: 3

        ID PRESSU      HEART         ID     HEIGHT     WEIGHT
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                                      3         71        165

SQL>
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes, this seems to have worked. I'm far from an expert so I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it definitely produces the results I am looking for.

Comment: an alternative to the `&par_value in (ta.id, tb.id)` is `COALSCE(ta.id, tb.id) = &par_value`, although I suspect there wouldn't be much of a performance difference either way.